# jQuery - set this Parent Element ID as a text

Tags: jquery

How can I display parent element id?

For Eg: Inside every span element, I want to display subgroup div's id as a text.

like : `<span class="mpei">sg-1</span>`

```
<div class="subgroup" id="sg-1">
  <span class="mpei"></span>
</div>
<div class="subgroup" id="sg-2">
  <span class="mpei"></span>
</div>
<div class="subgroup" id="sg-3">
  <span class="mpei"></span>
</div>
<div class="subgroup" id="sg-4">
  <span class="mpei"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: And shorter version: `$('.mpei').text(function() { return this.parentNode.id; });` [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29v0yrua/1/).

Comment: @Regent, was just typing `this.parentNode.id` to further improve your improved solution :P

Comment: @ShaunakD yes, I somewhy decided that `$(this).parent()[0]` will be shorter, but then I calculate attentively :)

Comment: Hi **@Regent**... You are just too good :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `each` to loop through all the `div` having class `subgroup`.

```
$('.subgroup').each(function() {
    $(this).children('.mpei').text($(this).attr('id'));
    // $(this).find('.mpei').text($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

`$(this)` inside `each` is the current element i.e. `.subgroup`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/jnsuc06j/

Answer (score 2):

1. Iterate through each div with class `.subgroup`
2. In each iteration `find` children `.mpei`
3. Set their `text()` with `attr('id')`

```js
$('.subgroup').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.mpei').text($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="subgroup" id="sg-1">
  <span class="mpei"></span>
</div>
<div class="subgroup" id="sg-2">
  <span class="mpei"></span>
</div>
<div class="subgroup" id="sg-3">
  <span class="mpei"></span>
</div>
<div class="subgroup" id="sg-4">
  <span class="mpei"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through spans and get the parent element id to assign to text.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kq9Lqmgf/)**

```
$('.mpei').each(function(){
   $(this).text($(this).parent().attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.each()` to iterate on `<span>` elements and then use `prop()` to get ID.

```
$('span.mpei').each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).closest('.subgroup').prop('id'))
});
```

```js
$('span.mpei').each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).closest('.subgroup').prop('id'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="subgroup" id="sg-1">
  <span class="mpei"></span>
</div>
<div class="subgroup" id="sg-2">
  <span class="mpei"></span>
</div>
<div class="subgroup" id="sg-3">
  <span class="mpei"></span>
</div>
<div class="subgroup" id="sg-4">
  <span class="mpei"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your quick and perfect answers.... all the examples are working great.. You Guys Rock :)

Answer (score 2):

use **jQuery each** for iteration . try this

```
$('.mpei').each(function(){
   $(this).text($(this).parent().attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: @Tushar yeah we both used same class name

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

```
$(".mpei").each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).parent().attr('id'));
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/s0f7xqyg/**